# Where can I declare the compute field function?

Tags: 8

Computed fields have a `computed_field_YOUR_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME_compute()` function to compute the field value.

In Drupal in which module I use this?

Comment: Any custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Any module can defined this function.